# Split unprocessed dataset into train and test sets

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have two files namely - `log.csv` and `label.csv`. My aim is to to split these files into training and testing datasets before preprocessing the log_train file further.

The `log.csv` file has a no. of columns including `id`. For one value of `id`, the file has 'z' no. of rows (this 'z' is different for different value of `id`) . Whereas, in the `label.csv` file there is just one row for each value of `id`.  I wish to split the files into - `log_train.csv`, `log_test.csv`, `label_train.csv` and `label_test.csv` obviously such that all rows corresponding to one value of `id` goes either to train or test file with corresponding values in label_train or label_test file.

I have already tried doing:
`X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df,df_label,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)`

but this gives me the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tmp.py", line 35, in <module>
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df,df_label,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
  File "/home/yamini/virtual/home/yamini/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2184, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/home/yamini/virtual/home/yamini/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 260, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/home/yamini/virtual/home/yamini/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [608, 3]`

How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Use scikit learn:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Kindly check my updated question.

Comment: You need to have the same number of samples in both arrays, otherwise, it doesn't work.

Comment: Matthieu is there a way to split the dataset into train and test sets when x value has a number of columns. I mean to say if I a have say `input1` and `input2` in x (which I want to split to x_train and x_test) and just `label` in y, can I somehow split it?

Comment: yes, you can, as long as they all have the same number of entries. You can put as many vectors/list/arrays as you want, you will get the same number of output elements.

Comment: the `input1` & `input2` have the shapes `(3, 24, 48, 1)` and 
`y_train:  (3,)` When I try `[input1,input2],[input1test,input2test],y_train,y_test = train_test_split([day1,day2],df_label,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)` It gives me `samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 3]` error.
`

Comment: You need to pass `day1` and `day2` as simple arguments, not a list. `train_test_split(day1, day2, df...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear as to what you gain by splitting the label file into training and testing since it sounds like a reference file. Do you expect the `id`s to be mutually exclusive to the train vs test file?  If so, that will involve a more complex, and perhaps, iterative process to get a good train / test mix.

If you don't expect the `id`s to be exclusive to one data set, I would just join the two data frames before performing the train/test split.  In this case, your code should work as is.

In case you need it, here is a link to merging data frames.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

**Update**

The simple way is below.

```
X_train,X_test=train_test_split(df_label,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
X_train = X_train.merge(df, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='inner')
X_test = X_test.merge(df, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='inner')
```

As I said though, the two data sets may be very imbalanced, but this is all I can do for you given the information you have disclosed.

Best of luck

Comment: I want to split the label file so I could use train file for training the model and the test one so I could see the accuracy of my predictions with the actual values. 

I cannot have same ids in both training and testing (formed by splitting the log file)as the label file has only one value for one id. The multiple rows of a unique `id` has a meaning, I cannot divide them into training and testing.

Comment: Then you should perform your split on the label file only and then join to the log file.  A word of warning though, this may not produce an evenly distributed data set.

Comment: how can I do that? Can you provide me a demo code or something?

Comment: your code gives me this error: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
`

Comment: Set the style of the column that is currently an object, to int64.

Comment: when I try using `y_train['id'] = y_train['id'].astype(int)` it gives me `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'`. Can you help me here?

Comment: Maybe the object field has a hidden space preventing the conversion to an int?

Comment: Even I suspect the same thing but couldn't figure out where, the `label.csv` file doesn't have a space.

Comment: I’m sorry I cannot help more